# Deserializing single-attribute JSON payload in Spring MVC controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to create controller methods that semantically look like the following

```
public HttpEntity<?> deleteUser(String userId){
...
}
```

The client is going to pass the user ID as part of the JSON payload. If I try to annotate `@RequestBody` the string parameter and issue a `{"userId":"foo"}` payload, then I get an exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7311a203; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:854) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2798) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
```

And that is reasonable because JSON wants to deserialize a complex object (with namely one attribute) into a `String`.

I also know that `"foo"` is not valid JSON. And I know that I **can** use a `Map<String,Object>` or even better a `ModelMap`, and as a last resort I could use query string and `@RequestParam`, **but** today I have been clearly asked by my boss to find a way to use a plain string instead of an object, in order for code to look more readable.

How can I force Jackson/MVC to deserialize only the "username" property into a plain old `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will usually see this type of error when Spring MVC finds a request mapping that matches the URL path but the parameters (or headers or something) don't match what the handler method is expecting.

If you use the @RequestBody annotation then  Spring MVC is expecting to map the entire body of the POST request to an Object,it dont work with String by default.

### **There are different way to do this as listed below:**

**1)** Change method type of deleteUser() method type to GET instead of Post and use userId as String.

**2)**  You could simply inject the HttpServletRequest into your method and read the body:

```
public void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String userID = IOUtils.toString( request.getInputStream());
  // do stuff
}
```

**3)** Use a wrapper (java model of the JSON object) that could replace the String parameter,and also this will work fine with the json coming in your post.

```
public class UserWrapper {

    private String userId;
    //getter setters
```

and then use in your controller as:

```
public void deleteUser(@RequestBody UserWrapper user) {
//do your stuff
}
```

**4)** Spring provides a way to configure multiple message converters as shown below:
**Note:** Then, requests to the various methods must specify the "content-type" header with an appropriate value. For those methods where the request body is mapped to a JAXB bean, specify "application/xml". And for those where the request body is a String, use "text/plain".

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            <ref bean="marshallingConverter" />
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this help you!