# Grab a specific property from JSON payload as MVC method argument

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have asked a *similar* question before: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234132/deserializing-single-attribute-json-payload-in-spring-mvc-controller)

Now I have a similar but different issue.

My Spring MVC controller model is a JSON payload with a defined set of attributes that, unfortunately, are not part of a class in my project.

E.g.

```
{
    "userId" : "john",
    "role" : "admin"
}
```

I need to treat `userId` and `role` as separate `String`s.

I currently have two ways to declare the controller method

```
public ResponseObject mvc(@RequestBody MyCustomDTO dto){

    String userId = dto.getUserId();
    String role = dto.getRole();
}

public ResponseObject mvc(@RequestBody ModelMap map){
    String userId = (String)map.get("userId");
    String role = (String)map.get("role");
}
```

I have been asked to find a different implementation because 1) requires to create a custom DTO class for each combination of parameters (most cases need 1 named parameter, e.g. `delete(productId)`) and 2) involves an entity that is not strictly defined. Especially when dealing with lists, it can contain arbitrary values that need to be checked at runtime.

Spring MVC, as I have found, does not support resolving `@ModelAttribute` from a JSON request body. Am I doing something wrong or is it just Spring not doing it? Can I grab a specific property, be it a plain primitive or an entire POJO, from the Request Body into a method argument?

In the second case it would be better to request a useful feature to Spring developers.

Spring version is 4.2.x.
This question is related with the previously linked but differs in the fact that now I will be encapsulating the single property into a Javascript object, so the object that Jackson needs to deserialize won't be a primitive but a POJO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get individual members as easily, simply because Spring MVC doesn't have any builtin tools to do that. One option is to write your own annotation that describes a parameter at the root of an excepted JSON object body. Then write and register a new [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/invocation/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) implementation which processes that annotation on a handler method parameter.

This is not a simple task. Since you can't consume the request content multiple times, you have to save it somehow, in a `Filter`, for example. For now, let's ignore this restriction and assume we only wanted one parameter. You'd define an annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@interface JsonObjectProperty {
    String name();
}
```

And the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

```
class JsonObjectPropertyResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    /**
     * Configured as appropriate for the JSON you expect.
     */
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(JsonObjectProperty.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
            WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        Class<?> parameterType = parameter.getParameterType();

        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        ServletServerHttpRequest inputMessage = new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest);
        MediaType contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
        if (!contentType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException(
                    "Could not read document. Expected Content-Type " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 + ", was " + contentType + ".");
        }
        // handle potential exceptions from this as well
        ObjectNode rootObject = objectMapper.readValue(inputMessage.getBody(), ObjectNode.class);
        if (parameterType == String.class) {
            JsonObjectProperty annotation = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonObjectProperty.class);
            return rootObject.get(annotation.name()).asText();
        }
        // handle more
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read document. Parameter type " + parameterType + " not parseable.");
    }
}
```

and finally the handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json-new", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String handleJsonProperty(@JsonObjectProperty(name = "userId") String userId) {
    String result = userId;
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

You'll have to register the `JsonObjectPropertyResolver` appropriately. Once you do, it will be able to extract that JSON property directly into the parameter.

Comment: Hi, first thanks a lot for your advice. I edited your answer and deleted the first part only because it was **exactly** what I did **not** want to do, because it is similar as to what I asked in my question. The rest is great and I hope that once I can make your implementation work in my project I will be able to push it to Spring project

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I thought you just didn't want a POJO.

Comment: ...and not a Map, or ModelMap :-) as those types are so generic you don't know what's inside them at compile time

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ That problem is unsolvable (+/-) if you don't know what's inside the JSON. But you do know what's inside the JSON otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the second solution either. Using the `JsonNode#asText`, you're asserting that the corresponding JSON is a JSON primitive (likely text).

Comment: Well.. not really. My problem is to define a compile-time signature for MVC controller methods. If I accept a POJO I am fixing a contract between client and server. At least/most the attributes in the DTO are expected in a request. If I use Map it is less clear what the server expects from client. The POJO/DTO is the most robust solution, however for simple arguments I don't like the idea of creating a new class, so that is why I am going to expect Spring inject the simple value into method args the same way it injects path variables and query/form attributes

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ This compile-time restriction you're searching for really is impossible for an HTTP service. This is typically handled by returning a 400 if the request is bad. This is what should happen with the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` in my second example (though for bad content, that should be 406). In the first example, the implication is that if `asText` threw an Exception, you'd handle that by returning a 400 response, possibly with an explanation. That's what Spring MVC does when it is unable to convert a path or form parameter to the requested type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JSON inline parsers (similar to XML Xpath) where you can provide your JSON string and ask your parser to retrieve some subdocument as String, List or Map. One of the examples is OGNL. It's quite powerful tool, although it is not the only one and not the most performance efficient, but still mature and stable Apache product. So, in your case you would be able feed your JSON string to OGNL and tell it to retrieve properties "userId" and "role" as separate strings. See the OGNL documentation at [Apache OGNL page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/)

Comment: Sorry but the point is to use shortest possible syntax. So I **need** to get the value as method argument **transparently**, **or** dig into Spring source code, develop my module to make it possible and then possibly submit a pull request to Spring. That is my boss's demand